# Replace all occurrences of the word "java" with uppercase "JAVA" without using regex or replace method

Tags: java, text, replace

I have an assignment to replace all occurrences of the word "java" with uppercase "JAVA" without using regex or replace method. Please see my code & output below. Please confirm if this is the best way to do that.

Code:

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Substitute
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String javaString = "java";
        String left, right, sub = "", result = "";
        int index;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a sentence with a word \"java\" and replaces every occurrence of it with \"JAVA\" or type \"quit\" to quit: ");
        String sentence = input.nextLine();
        while(!(sentence.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")))
        {   
            index = sentence.toLowerCase().indexOf("java");
            if(index != -1)
            {
                if(javaString.equalsIgnoreCase(sentence.substring(index, index + 4)))
                {
                    while(index != -1) 
                    {
                        left = sentence.substring(index, index + 4);
                        right = sentence.substring(index + 4);

                        if(sentence.indexOf(right) <= 0 || sentence.indexOf(right) >= sentence.length())
                        {
                            sub = sentence.substring(index, index + 4);
                            sub = sub.toUpperCase();
                            if(result == "")
                            {
                                result = sentence.substring(0, index) + sub;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                result = result.substring(0, index) + sub;
                            }
                            index = -1;
                        }
                        else if(sentence.indexOf(right) > 0 && sentence.indexOf(right) < sentence.length())
                        {
                            sub = sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf(left, index), sentence.indexOf(right, index));
                            sub = sub.toUpperCase();
                            if(result == "")
                            {
                                result = sentence.substring(0, (sentence.indexOf(left, index))) + sub + sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf(right, index));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                result = result.substring(0, (sentence.indexOf(left, index))) + sub + sentence.substring(sentence.indexOf(right, index));
                            }
                            index = sentence.toLowerCase().indexOf("java", index + 4);
                        }
                        if(index == -1)
                        {
                            System.out.println(result);
                        }
                    } //end of while loop
                    System.out.print("Please enter a sentence with a word \"java\" and replaces every occurrence of it with \"JAVA\" or type \"quit\" to quit: ");
                    sentence = input.nextLine();
                    index = sentence.toLowerCase().indexOf("java");
                    result = "";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("There is no word \"java\" in the sentence.");
                System.out.print("Please enter a sentence with a word \"java\" and replaces every occurrence of it with \"JAVA\" or type \"quit\" to quit: ");
                sentence = input.nextLine();
                index = sentence.toLowerCase().indexOf("java");
                result ="";
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

---

```
$ java Substitute
Enter a sentence with a word "java" and replaces every occurrence of it with "JAVA" or type "quit" to quit: Program
There is no word "java" in the sentence.

Please enter a sentence with a word "java" and replaces every occurrence of it with "JAVA" or type "quit" to quit: rogram java
rogram JAVA

Please enter a sentence with a word "java" and replaces every occurrence of it with "JAVA" or type "quit" to quit: s java and java
s JAVA and JAVA

Please enter a sentence with a word "java" and replaces every occurrence of it with "JAVA" or type "quit" to quit: ScriptJava
ScriptJAVA

Please enter a sentence with a word "java" and replaces every occurrence of it with "JAVA" or type "quit" to quit: p java
p JAVA

Please enter a sentence with a word "java" and replaces every occurrence of it with "JAVA" or type "quit" to quit: scjava
scJAVA

Please enter a sentence with a word "java" and replaces every occurrence of it with "JAVA" or type "quit" to quit: Javascript
JAVAscript

Please enter a sentence with a word "java" and replaces every occurrence of it with "JAVA" or type "quit" to quit: Programming java and java JaVa
Programming JAVA and JAVA JAVA

Please enter a sentence with a word "java" and replaces every occurrence of it with "JAVA" or type "quit" to quit: rogramming java and java JaVa
rogramming JAVA and JAVA JAVA

Please enter a sentence with a word "java" and replaces every occurrence of it with "JAVA" or type "quit" to quit: quit
```

Comment: definitely not a good way to do it. 1) you're comparing strings incorrectly, not a good habit to get into. 2) use a StringBuilder.

Comment: This is not a "check my code" site. If your code isn't working, then isolate the bug, and ask a question about it. If it's working, then we can't help you here, and you might want to consider posting a question on the code-review stackexchange site. But if you opt to do so, you'll still want to improve your question, including and especially giving a specific metric for how you want the code improved.

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot use StringBuilder in this assignment as well. But it is good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use indexOf to find index of word "java" and then concat left substring + replacement + right substring.

```
private String replace(String s, String what, String with){
    int index;
    while ((index = s.indexOf(what)) != -1){
        s = s.substring(0,index)+with+s.substring(index+what.length());
    }
    return s;
}

@Test
public void test(){
    TestCase.assertEquals(
            "Hello from JAVA, JAVA...JAVA",
            replace("Hello from java, java...java", "java", "JAVA")
    );
}
```